# Validation Message is shown even there is no error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validationsummary

I have created a form along with other fileds having validation and there is one field where it doesn't have the validationMessageFor but in validationSummary I am able to see the error for that field and model doesn't have the required property.

Comment: please post your model and view to get any response

Comment: Below is the Model
    
    public int a_initID{ get; set; }
    public string a_inty{ get; set; }
    public string a_iniNat{get;set;}
    public stirng a_initName {get;set;}

Comment: @NagibMahfuz       `using (Html.BeginForm("WorkFlow", "Work", FormMethod.Post, new { class = "form-horizontal", autocomplete = "off", id = "frmCr" }))
                            {
                                Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                Html.ValidationSummary()
                              
                                                        Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.a_initID, new { @class = "form-control" })            `

Comment: @NagibMahfuz did you get anuything.

Answer (score 0):

`Validation summary`  Is supposed to  display all the error messages on the model  irrespective of `validationMessageFor` usage in UI.
The field might contain any other validations associated with it. Please post your model here.

Comment: Below is the Model
    
    public int a_initID{ get; set; }
    public string a_inty{ get; set; }
    public string a_iniNat{get;set;}
    public stirng a_initName {get;set;}

Comment: `using (Html.BeginForm("WorkFlow", "Work", FormMethod.Post, new { class = "form-horizontal", autocomplete = "off", id = "frmCr" }))                             {                                 Html.AntiForgeryToken()                                 Html.ValidationSummary()                                                                                        Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.a_initID, new { @class = "form-control" })`